# React Redux Redux Form - moving a function from within a <Field> produces error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Novice.

I have a class Address which I ultimately want to split into a presentational component and container. It all works as is but when I move this particular function outside the render function from initially within the actual async.select form field -

```
    onSuburbChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
      input.onChange(value)
      updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
    })
  }
```

...I find I am getting hit with a number of errors based on the the fact that they are unreferenced.

The error I get is

> address.jsx:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

If I comment this line out I get the same type of error on updatePostcodeValue.

Here is the entire address file. As you can see it would be good to move the presentational section in render off to another file but I need to move all the functions to the outside of the render function.

NOTE: I have commented out where the function orginal sat so anybody who has a crack at this question knows where it was and also where I intended to move it...

```
      import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
      import { connect } from 'react-redux'
      import { Field, change } from 'redux-form'
      import { Col, Panel, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
      import Select from 'react-select'
      import { getSuburbs } from './actions'
      import FormField from '../formComponents/formField'
      import TextField from '../formComponents/textField'
      import StaticText from '../formComponents/staticText'

      import { CLIENT_FORM_NAME } from '../clients/client/client'

      export class Address extends Component {
        static contextTypes = {
          _reduxForm: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        }

        constructor(props, context) {
          super(props, context)

          this.state = {
            selectedSuburb: null,
          }
        }

        // Manage Select for new data request - for suburbs.
        handleSuburbSearch = (query) => {
          console.group('handleSuburbSearch')
          console.log('query', query)
          const { addressData } = this.props
          console.log('addressData', addressData)
          const companyStateId = addressData.companyStateId
          console.log('companyStateId', companyStateId)

          if (!query || query.trim().length < 2) {
            console.log('no query; bailing!')
            console.groupEnd()
            return Promise.resolve({ options: [] })
          }
          const queryString = {
            query: query,
            companyStateId: companyStateId,
          }
          console.log('queryString', queryString)
          return getSuburbs(queryString)
            .then(data => {
              console.log('Suburbs returned!', data)
              console.groupEnd()
              return { options: data }
            })
        }


        //I HAVE MOVED IT TO HERE....

        onSuburbChange = (value) => {
          this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
            input.onChange(value)
            updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
          })
        }


        render() {
          const { addressData, updatePostcodeValue } = this.props
          const { value } = this.state
          const sectionPrefix = this.context._reduxForm.sectionPrefix

          return (
            <Panel header={<h3>Client - Address Details</h3>}>
              <Row>
                <Field component={TextField}
                  name="address1"
                  id="address1"
                  type="text"
                  label="Address Line 1"
                  placeholder="Enter street 1st line..."
                  fieldCols={6}
                  labelCols={3}
                  controlCols={9}
                />
                <Field component={TextField}
                  name="address2"
                  id="address2"
                  type="text"
                  label="Address Line 2"
                  placeholder="Enter street 2nd line..."
                  fieldCols={6}
                  labelCols={3}
                  controlCols={9}
                />
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Field
                  component={props => {
                    const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props
                    const { fieldCols, labelCols, controlCols, label, inputClass } = props
                    // just the props we want the inner Typeahead textbox to have
                    const { name, onChange } = input
                    const onStateChange = (state) => {
                      console.log('onStateChange', state)
                      onChange(state)
                    }

                    return (
                      <FormField
                        id={id}
                        label={label}
                        fieldCols={fieldCols}
                        labelCols={labelCols}
                        controlCols={controlCols}
                        inputClass={inputClass}
                      >
                        <Select
                          name={name}
                          onChange={onStateChange}
                          placeholder="Select state"
                          valueKey="id"
                          options={addressData.states}
                          labelKey="stateLabel"
                          optionRenderer={option => `${option.stateShortName} (${option.stateName})`}
                          value={input.value}
                          selectValue={Array.isArray(input.value) ? input.value : undefined}
                        />
                      </FormField>
                    )
                  }}
                  name="state"
                  id="state"
                  label="State."
                  fieldCols={6}
                  labelCols={3}
                  controlCols={6}
                />
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Field
                  component={props => {
                    const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props
                    const { fieldCols, labelCols, controlCols, label, inputClass } = props
                    const { name, value, onChange, onBlur, onFocus } = input
                    const inputProps = {
                      name,
                      value,
                      onChange,
                      onBlur,
                      onFocus,
                    }

                    {/*onSuburbChange = (value) => {
                      this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
                        input.onChange(value)
                        updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
                      })
                    }*/}

                    return (
                      <FormField
                        id={id}
                        label={label}
                        fieldCols={fieldCols}
                        labelCols={labelCols}
                        controlCols={controlCols}
                        inputClass={inputClass}
                      >
                        <Select.Async
                          {...inputProps}
                          onChange={this.onSuburbChange}
                          valueKey="id"
                          labelKey="suburbName"
                          loadOptions={this.handleSuburbSearch}
                          backspaceRemoves={true}
                        />
                      </FormField>
                    )
                  }}
                  name="suburb"
                  id="AddressLocation"
                  label="Suburb."
                  fieldCols={6}
                  labelCols={3}
                  controlCols={9}
                />

              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Field component={StaticText}
                  name="postcode"
                  id="postcode"
                  label="Postcode."
                  fieldCols={6}
                  labelCols={3}
                  controlCols={9}
                />
              </Row>
            </Panel>
          )
        }
      }

      const AddressContainer = connect(state => ({
        addressData: state.addressData,
      }), dispatch => ({
        updatePostcodeValue: (postcode, sectionPrefix) => dispatch(change(CLIENT_FORM_NAME, `${sectionPrefix ? (sectionPrefix + '.') : ''}postcode`, postcode))
      }))(Address)

      export default AddressContainer
```

How do I structure the onSuburbChange so that it can sit outside the render function, update the onChange value and also update the Postcode etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you look at the method, you'll see that... well, input is undefined in that scope.

```
onSuburbChange = (value) => { // <-- scope starts here
    this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
        input.onChange(value) // <-- input used here
        updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
    })
}
```

assuming `Select.Async` is a "magic" blackbox Component that you don't have access to/are able to change, and the only parameter you get back from it in the callback is the new value, your best bet is a ref on the input.

```
<Field ref={(input) => this.input = input } ... />
```

and then change it to `this.input` instead of just `input`

I think you could also partially apply it (it's late any I'm not thinking straight) - it would look like

```
onSuburbChange = (input, value) => {
    this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
        input.onChange(value)
        updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
    })
}
```

--

`const mOnChange = onSuburbChange.bind(null, input)` while `input` is in scope.

`updatePostcodeValue` can be referenced from props in the callback - and you've already taken care of ensuring it has the correct scope by using ES6 arrow function notation. Just destructure it out of props just like you did in render at the top of the callback.

also, unrelated, but you REALLY oughta break out those `component` props into another file or function...

Comment: I am unsure where to place ref as its giving an error on the first bracket of ref={(input) => this.input = input } - "property assignment expected" and on the function arrow of  "; expected". Also I am also unsure how to destructure the updatePostcodeValue as you have suggested. Finally, if you, could you elaborate on breaking those component props to another file..

Comment: I moved ref={(input) => this.input = input } down into the async.select function and its not erroring anymore.. I am now getting an error on "input.onChange(value)" in the onSuburbChange function above - "input.onChange is not a function"

Comment: `property assignment expected` and `; expected` sound like eslint errors to me. destructure is exactly what you're doing now at the top of `render` - `const { updatePostcodeValue } = this.props`